# Online Application with a small processing fee required on submission

Tags: wordpress, civigrant, civipetiton

Using WordPress and iATS Payments

I need to setup up an online application for our school.  We charge a $25 processing fee. In reading the threads here, it appears I will need to use CiviPetition to do the Online Application. Or I was thinking about trying CiviGrants with the Grant Application Extension.  Does anyone know if we can require a fee payment with submission using either of these methods?

Comment: why can't you do this just with a Contribution page and a Profile for your data collection

Comment: I started down that path, but our application is too complicated for this to really work well.

Answer (score 1):

For Grant Application on Drupal: I recommend webform_civicrm module for application workflows:

- collect all contact info/fields you need (parents + child(ren) + emergency contacts)
- store the relationships between these contacts
- make it a nice looking multi page application
- add payment field(s) in the process

Comment: I looked at that. But it appears to be only compatible with Drupal CMS. We use Wordpress. But I would love to be corrected, because it does appear to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct there is no such integration w/ Wordpress;

Answer (score 1):

I came across two form Plugins that people have written additional plugins so that they interact with CiviCRM.

The first one I tried was Caldera Forms. Here is the github link to the civi integration https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm
I only recommend Caldeara Forms if you have a basic form. I finally gave up and asked for a refund.

The second form that I found was Gravity Forms. Here is the integration link. http://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/
I was able to set up our application with all the extras that we wanted with Gravity Forms. I highly recommend Gravity Forms.
I ended up not using the above integration because I have a redirect in place, when they click submit, that takes them to the Application Fee page. When they pay the fee, then I have their contact info in Civi. This is less than ideal because they are not forced to pay it, but it is put right in front of them.